# How do I seed the master data during "OnModelCreating" method of DbContext in case of auto generated primary key enabled?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, database-migration

Application Framework: `ASPNET Core 2.1`

This is my class

```
public class Employee
{
    [DataMember(Name = "key")]
    [Key]
    public Guid Key { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have below code which enable the seeding of data and auto generation of `Guid` column

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Auto generation of Guid
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().Property(x => x.Key).HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");

        //seeding of data
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasData(
            new Employee{ Name = "Hamlet" },
            new Employee{ Name = "King Lear" },
            new Employee{ Name = "Othello" }
        );
    }
```

I get the below error while running the `add-migration InitialCreate` command

> The seed entity for entity type 'Employee' cannot be added because there was no value provided for the required property 'Key'.

I do not want to send the value for `Key`. I want it to be auto-generated in SQL Server database.

My basis requirement is : Insert master data (updated) whenever I run `update-database` in the package manager console.

Comment: So far, the `HasData` method doesn't have an overload that accepts a matching key specification, as `AddOrUpdate` has. It could be a feature request. Until then your only option is to specify the key value. Note however, that you're always going to need the specified key if you also want to seed data referring to `Employee`.

Answer (score 1):

<del>Try adding the following attribute to the `Key` property:.</del>

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

<del>This will instruct the DB to autogenerate the `Key` when none is specified</del>

## Update

[Apparently](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11776#issuecomment-383662924) you have to always specify the ID even for autogenerated for the data seeded in migrations, because it is used to match if the given entry is already present in the database.

However, a solution can be to manually insert the needed records in the database after it is initialized (after you call `context.Database.Migrate()` for example). Of course here you have to manually check if the given record is not already there.

Comment: not working. it show same error, I already have modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().Property(x => x.Key).HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");  for auto generation. 'add-migration' works if I remove the seed data code. so what is the alternative option to seed data?

Comment: It resolved the issue but did not solve the need. It's inserting the key's which I have specified as you suggested. I wish to see auto generated guids in the database.

Comment: If you combine the updated part of my question as well as the `[DatabaseGenerated(Identity)]` attribute, it should work

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the identity value manually during seeding:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Auto generation of Guid
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().Property(x => x.Key).HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");

        //seeding of data
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasData(
            new Employee{ Key = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Hamlet" },
            new Employee{ Key = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "King Lear" },
            new Employee{ Key = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Othello" }
        );
    }
```